# BroadCasting an offline transaction

Tags: ethereum, web3js, web3-java

I want to broadcast a raw ETH transaction and pay the fees for it in web3j, i used the following code to get the hex value of the transaction

```
EthGetTransactionCount ethGetTransactionCount = web3j.ethGetTransactionCount(credentials.getAddress(), DefaultBlockParameterName.PENDING).send();
        BigInteger nonce =  ethGetTransactionCount.getTransactionCount();
        
        RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, to, value);

        // Sign the Transaction
        byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, credentials);

        String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);
        System.out.println(hexValue);
```

How can i broadcast and pay the transaction fees of the hex value using my wallet ?

Answer (score 1):

simply doing something like this:

```
EthSendTransaction result = web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(hexValue).send();
String hash = result.getTransactionHash();
```